# aggregate changes between statuses

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have snapshot table with below structure and data:

```
SnapshotDate,  DepartmentID,           Status,   EmployeeName
20210201,      deptA,                  High,     employee1
20210201,      deptB,                  Medium,   employee2
20210201,      deptA,                  Low,      employee3
20210202,      deptA,                  Low,      employee1
20210202,      deptB,                  High,     employee2
20210202,      deptA,                  Low,      employee3
```

I would like to count for each date and department changes between statuses in each combination just like below:

```
StatusFrom, StatusTo,   Date,          DepartmentID,      NumOfChanges
Low,        Low,        20210202,      deptA,             1
High,       Low,        20210202,      deptA,             1
Medium,     High,       20210202,      deptB,             1
```

any ideas? how to do it optimally? thanks for all advices.

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lag()` and aggregation:

```
select status, prev_status, snapshotdate, departmentid, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             lag(status) over (partition by employeename, departmentid order by snapshotdate) as prev_status
      from t
     ) t
where snapshotdate = '20210202'
group by status, prev_status, snapshotdate, departmentid;
```